# only using select in sql instead of group by

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
supplier  | product  | qty
--------------------------
  s1      |    p1    | 300
  s1      |    p2    | 90
  s2      |    p3    | 89
```

I want to find suppliers with more than 2 products.
But only with select and where, no `group by`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you want to use group by?

Comment: Your question is like saying "I want to select a certain record without using WHERE". GROUP BY exists for a reason. Furthermore, it applies perfectly to your needs in this case. If you want to avoid it because you don't understand it, I recommend that you read up on it (W3 schools has a good page) and learn how to code properly. Doing things in roundabout ways becuase you don't understand a concept will often lead you into big problems later on once your code becomes more complex.

Comment: Is this homework? Looks like Chris Date's supplier/parts database.

Comment: I know sql ... it is just a challenge that me and my friend are thinking about it ...

Comment: @MartinSmith Not a homework, but a challenge that my friend ask and we can not do it now

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want not to use group by is beyond me, but this might work:

```
SELECT Supplier FROM table outer WHERE 
  (
   select count(Products) from table inner 
   where inner.Supplier = outer.Supplier
  ) > 2
```

Please bear in mind, that group by is made for stuff like that and should be used.

Comment: This uses an *implicit* GROUP BY.  You may not have typed the letter, but by using an *aggregate* function such as `COUNT(*)` you're getting one.

Answer (score 2):

In the usual [parts and suppliers database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppliers_and_Parts_database), this relvar is named `SP`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.SNO 
  FROM SP AS T1 
          JOIN SP AS T2 
             ON T1.SNO = T2.SNO
                AND T2.PNO <> T1.PNO
          JOIN SP AS T3
             ON T1.SNO = T3.SNO
                AND T3.PNO <> T1.PNO
                AND T3.PNO <> T2.PNO;
```

Noting that you can use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.SNO 
  FROM SP AS T1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT 1
                 FROM SP AS T2
                WHERE T2.SNO = T1.SNO
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
              );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    supplier,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY supplier ORDER BY product) AS supplier_product_ordinal
  FROM
    YourTable
)
SELECT
  supplier
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  supplier_product_ordinal = 3
```

But I'd expect it to be slower than using GROUP BY.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  supplier
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable AS lookup WHERE supplier = yourTable.supplier AND product < yourTable.product)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable AS lookup WHERE supplier = yourTable.supplier AND product > yourTable.product);
```

Comment: haha, second query is funny and like mine, but one step smarter. Anyway, +1

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY S) AS Cnt
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT DISTINCT S
FROM T
WHERE Cnt > 2
```

Comment: +1 - Sticks to the letter of the request while still using aggregations. Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

with subquery:

```
select distinct supplier
from table a
where (select count(*) 
       from table b 
       where b.supplier = a.supplier and b.product <> a.product
       ) > 1
```